# Long tweet message got cut using tweepy in Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I noticed that using the below code, I cannot retrieve the long tweet; somehow it got cut. Can anyone suggest a way to retrieve the full tweet message?

```
tweets = []

#for month in range(8,13,1):
for i,j in zip(start_time,end_time):
    print(i)
    print(j)
    for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, 
                                     query = 'สมอง -is:retweet lang:th',
                                     user_fields = ['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
                                     tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text'],
                                     expansions = ['author_id', 'geo.place_id'],
                                     start_time = i,
                                     end_time = j):
                                     #max_results=500):
        time.sleep(1)
        tweets.append(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your snippet since I don't have the credentials but can you try something like this:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client("paste your token")

query = 'สมอง -is:retweet lang:th'
tweets = tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query,
                        user_fields = ['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
                        tweet_fields=['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text'],
                        max_results=100).flatten(limit=1000)

for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)  ## this should give you the full tweet
```

Please note to change the respective search method (**search_all_tweets**). I couldn't use it since it was asking for credentials for v2. You can also get rid of the `flatten` if you don't want only the data part of your tweet.